# Not able to render api response data into form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am not able to render api response to form, i am using same form for add and for edit too. i want when i click on Add button it should show initial empty value , but when i click edit button , it should so particular user data , but i am not able to achieve it.

I have tried

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { globalC } from "./context";

export default function DashboardForm() {
  const { detail, apiCalling } = useContext(globalC);
  useEffect(() => {
    apiCalling(id);
  }, []);
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const action = pathname.split("/")[1];

  const [name, setName] = useState(action === "add" ? "" : detail.name);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
      <form>
        <input
          name="name"
          type="text"
          placeholder="name"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <input
          name="username"
          type="text"
          placeholder="username"
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <input
          name="email"
          type="text"
          placeholder="email"
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i am use class based context api , user get api is called in context,

Codesandbox link : [link](https://x1s27.csb.app/login)

login and go to dashboard to try the example

Answer (score 0):

Mind that your `useState` for `name` will be first called when the API call hasn't succeeded yet, giving you an empty name. Then once you do get the proper name in `detail`, the state is already created.

One solution would be something like:

```js
if (!name && detail.name) {
    setImmediate(() => setName(detail.name));
}
```

So once the API call gave you the name, and while the name input field is still empty, update it with the received name.

Another solution is to only show the form once the API request succeeded, and show a loading screen in the meantime.

Comment: i tried this problem with this is, when i do add it data populates correctly but when empty the input box it automatically populte name again

Comment: A simple fix would be keeping a small state variable saying whether you've already populated the field before. A more complex fix would be passing a callback to your API call, and populate the field during the one time the callback gets called.